# Trouble Migrating from Google Sign-In

Tags: angular, typescript, google-oauth, google-signin

I have trouble Migrating from Google Sign-In.

> "{error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}"

How can I use the newer one and replace the auth2 code and gapi commands to make it integrated with the new one? Very thankful for help to understand!

index.html code:

```
<head>
  <meta name = "google-signin-client-id" content ="XXXX.googleusercontent.com
  ">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess ="onSignIn" data-longtitle="true"></div>

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

google-signin.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleSigninService {

  private auth2: gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth
  private subject = new ReplaySubject<gapi.auth2.GoogleUser> (1)

  constructor() { 
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
member (the above private auth2)
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'XXXXXX....apps.googleusercontent.com'
      })
    })
  }
  public signIn(){
    this.auth2.signIn({
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
    }).then (user => {
      this.subject.next(user)
    }).catch( () => {
      this.subject.next(null)
    }) 
  }
  public signOut(){
    this.auth2.signOut()
      .then( () => {
        this.subject.next(null)
      })
  }
  public observable(): Observable <gapi.auth2.GoogleUser>{
    return this.subject.asObservable()
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';
import { GoogleSigninService } from './google-signin.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'google-signin';
  user: gapi.auth2.GoogleUser;

  constructor(private signInService: GoogleSigninService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef , private dialog: MatDialog, private router: Router) {}
  companySwipe(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/companyswipe');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signInService.observable().subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user
      this.ref.detectChanges()
    })
  }

  signIn (){
    this.signInService.signIn()
  }

  signOut(){
    this.signInService.signOut()
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "gapi", "gapi.auth2"]
  },
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click) ="signIn()" *ngIf = "user == null"> GOOGLE SIGNIN</button>
<button (click) = "signOut()" *ngIf = "user  != null" > GOOGLE SIGNOUT</button>
<div *ngIf ="user != null">
  <div> You are signed in with Google! {{user.getBasicProfile().getName()}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the Google Idendity Service library in your head tag:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
```

install the [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.accounts/index.d.ts):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/google.accounts
```

In your service initialize the client

```
this.tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
  client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
  scope: "THE_REQUESTED_SCOPES",
  prompt: "SELECT_A_PROMPT_OPTION", // '' | 'none' | 'consent' | 'select_account'
  callback: this.handleCredentialResponse // your function to handle the response after login. 'access_token' will be returned as property on the response
});
```

After signin, your get a response with an 'access_token' property. Store it in localstorage.

to signin call `requestAccessToken` on the `tokenClient`:

```
this.tokenClient.requestAccessToken(overrideConfig) // open the prompt,
```

overrideConfig is optional, options can be found in the [types declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.accounts/index.d.ts)

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you so much for fast response. 

It does not work so I think I might not fully understand where in the code this is to be implemented. Could you show me exactly what has been removed/replaced and where this initiation and request would be?

Comment: Change your `auth2` property in your `GoogleSigninService` to the new `tokenclient`. And in your signin method call `requestAccessToken`. Remove all references to `àuth2`. This will just return a JWT access token, no `GoogleUser`. To obtain the user information from the JWT follow these guidelines: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtaininguserprofileinformation